# How to get the HTTP request as a string from PHP HTTP Stream

Tags: php, http, stream

I'm using PHP Streams to make HTTP calls with fopen().  I would like print the HTTP request as a string (headers and content) before it is sent via fopen().

Is there a function that handles the stream context variable to do this?  If so, would someone be kind enough to post a brief example of this?

Here is a function that expects a URL, fetches it and returns the content:

```
function do_post_request ($url, $content, $cookie = null) {
  $headers = array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   $cookie);

  $all_headers = implode("\r\n", $headers)."\r\n";
  $params = array('http' => array("method" => "POST",
                                  "content" => $content,
                                  "header" => $all_headers,
                                 ),
                 );

  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (empty($fp)) {
    throw new Exception("$url: Failed");
  }
  $resp = stream_get_contents($fp);

  if (empty($resp)) {
    throw new Exception("error: bad fetch");
  }
  return $resp
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. Where do you need these headers for before doing any request?

Comment: In short, for debugging.  I'm connecting to a custom web service and I need to make sure that both the HTTP client headers and content are what I expect them to be.

Comment: So. after the fact (i.e. not _before_ the sending) would be good enough? I'd either do that by using `cURL` or `HTTPRequest`, which support this natively. If you really need it with `fopen` & context parameters, I think you'd have to create a proxy wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use PEAR's [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) which supports intercepting and logging sent headers.